# Change font size by container

Tags: javascript, css, font-size, viewport-units

I tried to use previous posts on this site and searches in google, but I'm missing something.

```js
var divContainer = ws_popupWindows.document.getElementById('sw_content');

divContainer.innerHTML = '<div id="sw_resize">' + msgTEXT.innerHTML + '</div>';

var spanContainer = ws_popupWindows.document.getElementById('sw_resize');
for (var newSize = 100; (newSize -= 10) && (divContainer.clientWidth < spanContainer.clientWidth);) {
  spanContainer.style.fontSize = newSize + '%';
}
```

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  direction: rtl;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: AntiqueWhite;
  font-size: 15vmin;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
h1 {
  height: 20vh;
  margin: 1vh;
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 100%
}
div {
  max-height: 70vh;
  background-color: Snow;
  margin: 0 5vh;
  padding: 2vh;
  border-radius: 10vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div id="sw_content">
  <div id="sw_resize">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
</div>
```

But it's not changing the size of the text.
(I cannot use jQuery, but it should not be so hard in pure JS too).

P.S:
I know the posts like [Dynamically resize font size to fit container size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17001302/dynamically-resize-font-size-to-fit-container-size), but it is still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the spanContainer's scroll height vs its clientHeight.

```
for (var newSize = 100; spanContainer.scrollHeight > spanContainer.clientHeight; newSize -= 10)
{
  spanContainer.style.fontSize = newSize + '%';
}
```